# Why do pandas DataFrame.boxplot() and DataFrame.plot.box() give different results?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

The docs for Python's pandas library suggest that [DataFrame.boxplot()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) and [DataFrame.plot.box()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.box.html) and [DataFrame.plot(kind='box')](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) are aliases.  However, consider the following code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd

data = [{'number': 2, 'group': 'A'},
        {'number': 4, 'group': 'B'},
        {'number': 1, 'group': 'A'},
        {'number': 5, 'group': 'B'},
        {'number': 2, 'group': 'A'},
        {'number': 4, 'group': 'B'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.boxplot(by='group');
```

[image: Correct boxplot[2]]

I think that using this alternative syntax should do the same thing:

```
df.plot.box(by='group');
```

However, it produces this:

[image: Incorrect plot.box()]

Do you have any idea why they produce different output?

For what it's worth, `df.plot(kind='box', by='group');` produces the same output as `df.plot.box(by='group');`

As a bonus question, how do I make the title in the `boxplot()` example not overlap?

Versions:

- Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016,
  11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
- pandas 0.19.2
- numpy 1.11.3
- matplotlib 2.0.0

Comment: I got exactly the same behaviour. And based on [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15079) from early in 2017 I think this behaviour is a bug. But FYI I'm still researching. I got around it by using DataFrame.boxplot but am not satisfied with the labelling which is why I was investigating DataFrame.plot.box.
Rgds,
Carl.